# Generate A Short Integer From A Unique String Without .GetHashCode()

Tags: c#, string, type-conversion

I'd like to generate a short integer when given a unique string. Note the string will never be more than 3 characters long, only alpha characters, can be either upper or lower case. For instance, `AB` should not return the same value as `BA`. I tried something like the following (below), only to run into `BA` being equal to `AK`:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static int StringToASCIIValue(this string str)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str)) 
            throw new ArgumentException("string must not be null or whitespace");

        int result = 0;
        foreach (char singleChar in str)
        {
            result = 10 * result + singleChar - '0';
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to avoid `GetHashCode`?

Comment: I don't really see the benefit of trying to restrict the integer you're getting from this. An `int` takes the space of an `int`, whether it comes from `GethashCode` or whether you calculate it using "smaller" numbers.

Comment: The simplest way would be to convert each character to its ascii value and then concatenate the two into one integer. Then `AB = 6566`, `BA = 6665`, `AK = 6575`, etc. No two combinations will be the same

Comment: @TheBatman's approach is pretty good, but just know that if you decide you need to be able to convert back, you'll need a little extra logic (eg. Is `11165` supposed to convert back to `111` and `65` or to `11` and `165`? Obviously only the first one is valid in your specific case).

Comment: @BrootsWaymb I need to know these numbers beforehand for an enumeration.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you're **really** sure you're not ever looking at more than 3 alphabetic (`A-Z` or `a-z`) characters, you should be able to just get the `ASCII` encoded bytes and convert them directly to an `int`.

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static int ToInt32(this string str)
    {
        // Checks for null omitted.
        var ascii = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str);
        int result = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < ascii.Length; i++)
        {
            result = result | (ascii[i] << (i * 8));
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

If it matters, you can then take that `int` back to the `string` that generated it.

```
public static class StringExtensions
{   
    public static string AsciiIntBackToString(this int value)
    {
        var bytes = BitConverter
            .GetBytes(value)
            .Where(b => b > 0)
            .ToArray();
        return System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple way to accomplish this. No two results will be the same. We take the string, then for each character in it we append the ascii value to a string builder. When we are done we can output a unique integer for that character combination.

```
string first = "AB";
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

foreach(char c in first)
{
     stringBuilder.Append((int)c);
}

Console.WriteLine(stringBuilder.ToString());
```

Output

```
6566
```

Comment: You can get the same output by simply using `string.Concat(first.Select(c => (int)c))`.

Comment: Unfortunately; char is a very wide concept, and the following two will result in the same hash: 'int i1 = ("" + (char)1234 + (char)567).StringToASCIIValue(); int i2 = ("" + (char)123 + (char)4567).StringToASCIIValue();'

Comment: @OguzOzgul char is a wide concept, but "alpha characters, lower and upper case" is not. Those were the constraints provided by the OP.

Comment: @TheBatman how about ÜĞİŞÇÖ and üğışçö which are the non-ASCII Turkish upper case and lower case characters. Do you see them correctly? If yes, that is thanks to the browser supporting UTF-8. If you are really intent on saying that "alpha characters, lower and uppercase is not a wide concept", I invite you to read about character sets, unicode, UTF-8, UTF-16 etc.